# Equals height of Spacer in two different Stacks

Tags: swift, stack, swiftui

For example, I have this view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TarifsScreen: View {

var body: some View {

    GeometryReader { geometry in

        VStack {

            VStack() {

                Spacer()

                Text("Text1")

                Spacer()

                Text("Text2")

                Spacer()

                Text("Text3")

                Spacer()

                Text("Text4")

                Spacer()

                VStack() {

                    Spacer()

                    Text("Text5")

                    Spacer()

                    Text("Text6")

                    Spacer()

                    Text("Text7")

                    Spacer()

                    Text("Text8")

                    Spacer()
                }
            }

        }.frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
    }
}
```

}

Spacer in lower stack is very big, but Spacer in higher stack is small. How can I make equals heights of all Spacers? I can't use only one stack for all elements, because I have > 10 elements in total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is only in >10 subviews, then `Group` using would be much simpler

```
var body: some View {

    GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack {
            Group {
                Spacer()
                Text("Text1")
                ...
            }
            Group {
                Spacer()
                Text("Text5")
                ...
            }
            ...
```

also if you have same regular patter worth considering `ForEach` (it makes grouping automatically), like

```
var body: some View {

    GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack {
            ForEach(0 ..< count) { index in
                Spacer()
                Text("Text\(index)")
            }
        }
```